# Действие после второго нажатия на кнопку (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if, while, click

**Как скрыть кнопку после второго нажатия на неё?**

Сейчас скрывается только по нажатию, **а необходимо "автоматически" когда c=2**.

Пробую циклы задавать, но видимо где-то ошибаюсь.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  c = 0;
  if (c >= 2) {
    $(".addRoom").css('display', 'none');
  };
  $('.addRoom').on('click', function() {
    if (c >= 2) {
      $(".addRoom").css('display', 'none');
    } else {
      $(".newRoom").clone().appendTo(".block").removeClass('newRoom').addClass('newAdded');
      c = c + 1;
      console.log(c);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="newRoom">newRoom</div>
</div>


<button class="addRoom">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.addRoom').on('click', function() {
    var c = $(this).data("c") || 0;
    if (c++ < 2) {
      $(".newRoom").clone().appendTo(".block").removeClass('newRoom').addClass('newAdded');
      console.log(c);
    }
    if (c >= 2)
      $(this).hide();
    $(this).data("c", c);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="newRoom">newRoom</div>
</div>


<button class="addRoom">Add</button>
```

Comment: Поставьте галочку если ответ вам помог